# Error when using scrapy for Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been trying to run scrapy to scrape websites and everytime I try to run one I run into some issues. When I run on the command line

```
scrapy crawl [FILE]
```

I get back a bunch of errors that start with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\boto\utils.py", line 210, in     r
etry_url
r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
  response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
  '_open', req)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
   return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2015-08-06 14:50:49 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
```

What exactly is stopping me from running Scrapy?

**EDIT**
I looked around stackoverflow and change my settings a bit which seemed to get rid of an error but these errors still remain.
I tried running scrapy shell and it also gives me error which I believe relate to the error I am receiving currently.

```
2015-08-08 15:08:27 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2015-08-08 15:08:27 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, bot
o
2015-08-08 15:08:27 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings:     {'LOGSTATS_INTERVAL': 0}

2015-08-08 15:08:27 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider,       TelnetConsol
e, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-08-08 15:08:28 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2015-08-08 15:08:29 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\lib\site-packages\boto\utils.py", line 210, in     retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
'_open', req)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
  result = func(*args)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
  return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
File "C:\Users\lib\urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
  raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2015-08-08 15:08:29 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2015-08-08 15:08:29 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:     HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware,   RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-08-08 15:08:29 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-08-08 15:08:29 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-08-08 15:08:29 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
```

Comment: Do any of the answers in this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306747/unable-to-read-instance-data-giving-up-error-in-python-boto

Comment: Not really. It gives me the impression that the error is caused by something in boto but I don't know what is causing it.

Comment: Found the answer at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048130/scrapy-gives-urlerror-urlopen-error-timed-out#comment50127480_31048130

Answer (score 3):

Try disabling the S3 handler by adding the following line to the file `~/your_project/settings.py`:

```
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {'s3': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your program is timing out because of too many frequent requests from pages of a same site. Try setting delay between downloading pages.

Check out [Scrapy documentation for download delay](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-DOWNLOAD_DELAY).

Comment: It doesn't work for any site that I try. I attempted to use other people's code and it still gave me this error.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to python using system set proxy. To disable it, you can make the following changes:

import os

os.environ['http_proxy']=''

Comment: Do i just add those two lines of code in before my own code?

Comment: Will you provide your code snippet? so that possible solutions can be framed

Comment: I used the tutorial that scrapy provides and I still obtain an error. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html. When I ran "scrapy crawl dmoz", the error appears.